# Cross multiplication on inner joins in Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have three tables in Access with the following structure (picture attached):

[image]

I am creating a query to pull information from all three tables with a join on "ID". Table 3 actually has multiple records for each ID, whereas "Table 2" has just one record per each ID. For some reason the result of the query is as follows: the correct sum for IDs in tables 3 and cross product for values in Table 2 (let's say there are three instances of ID# 1 in table 3: I would get 800 in Actual data (table 3) and i would get 3000 in Budget Data, which is 1000 times the number of records for ID#1 in table 3). Why does this cross multiplication happen if I have joined table 2 and table 3 to table 1 on ID?

Thank you

Comment: What's your query?  If you join to `table 3` on `ID`, you will definitely get multiple records.  Do you perhaps mean to aggregate `table 3`, and join on the totals?

Comment: I did join to table 3 on ID. I am new to Access and SQL, so I did not realize all the implications of having tables with different structures. I assumed that the query would aggregate data in both tables based on ID. I just didn't want to have a bunch of access queries stacked on top of each other. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using Sub Query
Try as below..

```
     SELECT A.Id,
    A.OpenDate,
    A.CloseDate,
    B.BudgetData,
    (SELECT SUM(C.ActualData) FROM Table3 C WHERE C.Id=A.Id) ActualData
    FROM Table1 A
        LEFT JOIN Table2 B
    ON A.Id=B.Id
```